# Segmentation of bees in image

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have an image of bees, for each bee in the image, I have - 
1) the coordinates of the bee (x, y) in the image
2) the orientation of the bee (with respect to the y-axis)

I want to train a Mask-RCNN on the given image, for training Mask-RCNN I need the outline of each bee instance.

[image: This is the image I have]

I tried drawing an ellipse over each bee instance, which looked like
[image: Elipse on each bee]

But I want a more fine-tuned version of the masks, maybe some segmentation techniques can help me.

These are the things that come to my mind -

1) K-means clustering, since I have the location of each bee in the image. (Treat each bee as the centroid)

**Any help or suggestion is appreciated**

Comment: These ellipses are drawn by hand or automatically using the centroid coordinate and the orientation? The bees' size and shape in this image look very homogeneous. If the annotations (center+orientation) are actually accurate you can have a very good starting point for the segmentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, these annotations were drawn automatically using centroid and orientation. Yes, the bees' size is homogenous but they are also very similar to the background. I used GrabCut and Active-contour modeling but did not get satisfactory results. Is there any other technique that I could try?

Comment: So it seems that the annotations are not entirely accurate. You can try using more accurate average-bee-shaped polygon rather than ellipse, but I don't think it will give you satisfactory results.
What about semi-manual segmentation tools like [Supervisely](https://supervise.ly/) or any [other tool](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-image-annotation-tools-available-out-there) available on-/off-line?
After you have several annotated examples it will be easier to train a model to annotate others.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about different techniques, snake_contour did the job for me. I had to adjust the hyperparameter's value by trying out different values. The resulting masks are -

[image]